# Laravel Elixir wrong paths

Tags: laravel, laravel-elixir

This is my gulpfile.js

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.less([
       'style.less'
    ], 'public/css/style.css')
        .styles([
       'reset.css',
       'font-awesome.min.css',
       'style.css'
    ], 'public/css/app.css', 'public/css')
    .scripts(['jquery-1.12.0.min.js', 'main.js'], 'public/js/app.js', 'resources/assets/scripts')
    .version(['css/app.css', 'js/app.js']); 
});
```

As result I get files

public/build/app-2a14246111.css
public/build/app-7790e07dfb.js
public/build/rev-manifest.json

but when I try to add css and js files to layout

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ elixir("css/app.css") }}">    
<script src="{{ elixir("js/app.js") }}"></script>
```

I get

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/build/css/app-2a14246111.css">
<script src="/build/js/app-7790e07dfb.js"></script>
```

and browser can't find them because it tries to find

```
http://localhost:8080/build/css/app-2a14246111.css
http://localhost:8080/build/js/app-7790e07dfb.js
```

and project folder name and public folder are missed somehow in paths. How to fix it?

Actually I see, I can add dot in paths like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href=".{{ elixir("css/app.css") }}">
<script src=".{{ elixir("js/app.js") }}"></script>
```

and then all will work, but I don't like this kind of fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you're running the Laravel project on localhost. When you deploy the project to a server, the problem resolves itself (assuming it's configured correctly).

If you're using Apache, you can add a Virtual Host configuration so that instead of `http://localhost:8080/laravel/public` you can use something like `http://domain-name.app`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>   
    DocumentRoot "C:\Users\username\path\to\laravel\public" 
    ServerName domain-name.app
</VirtualHost>
```

And then in your hosts file add:

```
127.0.0.1   domain-name.app
```

This way, you can link to absolute paths in your HTML like `/css/somefile.css` instead of `./css/somefile.css`.

Checkout [Homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/master/homestead), from Laravel, it helps to avoid a lot of pain in the ass.

Comment: Thanks a lot for giving the idea. I use XAMPP now, is there any way to add virtual host here?

Comment: @Heidel yes, it's possible with XAMPP. Just google about it.

Comment: I added `<VirtualHost *:8080>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\snimu\public"
    ServerName snimu
</VirtualHost>` in httpd-vhosts.conf (my XAMPP use 8080 port) and added `127.0.0.1    snimu www.snimu` in hosts file but page not found

Comment: did you restart XAMPP? Also www.snimu without domain extension looks odd, you should add an extension IMO.

Comment: Yes, I did restart XAMPP. I changed domain snimu.com and restarted XAMPP but page not found again.

Comment: I think it should use port 80, not 8080. Try that.

Comment: I've found out the problem with creating virtual host -- I forgot uncomment line `NameVirtualHost *:80` in `httpd-vhosts.conf` file. After I did that, virtual host `snimu.com` became available, and links `<script src="{{ elixir("js/app.js") }}"></script>` and `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ elixir("css/app.css") }}">` work fine.

Answer (score 3):

FWIW... you can also wrap the elixir tags with URL::asset like this:

```
<link href="{{ URL::asset(elixir('css/app.css')) }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

That solved my issue and still allowed me to run on port 8888.