# elixir adds extra slash before css version file path

Tags: laravel, laravel-elixir

I am using laravel and nodejs on WAMP Server on Windows 10. Now using the elixir mix function

`elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.sass('app.scss');
    mix.version('css/app.css');
});`

which is generating a version file for my app.css and placing it to

```
public\build\css\app-d37b3a9d94.css
```

now when I add the link of the css file by using elixir function, like following

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ elixir('css/app.css') }}">`

it generates a path like

`/build/css/app-d37b3a9d94.css`

but with this, the css do not work on the resulted page. I troubleshoot the problem and found that it do not work due to the first slash in the path. when I manually add the above css file path (which elixir generated) by removing the first slash, it works. like the following

`build/css/app-d37b3a9d94.css`

I am not sure how to fix this problem where elixir generated path to css file work. Looks like elixir adding an extra slash before the path but I have checked the code on several places for laravel and the code works with first slash in path. Not sure why it is not working for me.

One more thing I have noticed, even if I remove `mix.version('css/app.css');` from gulpfile.js (which generate version file) and run gulp command to update css/app.css, and use `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ elixir('css/app.css') }}">` it still refer to the version file rather than referring to css/app.css Is it a correct behavior?

Comment: @TheFallen I have used asset(elixir('css/app.css')) as you suggested but it started to convert the URL from Relative to Absolute like 'http://localhost/laravelproject/public/build/css/app-86a3953e5a.css"

Comment: Here is the soultion-> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35038394/laravel-elixir-wrong-paths?rq=1 I was going crazy with this too.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use it this way:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset(elixir('css/app.css')) }}">`